# how to get character key from an array of letters

Tags: javascript

I know how to get the key of a character. for example `console.log(String.fromCharCode(70))`  would log the letter F

but how do I do the opposite and get the CharCode from a single letter string?

**What I tried:**

---

```js
function solution(someword) {
  let oneArray = someword.split("");
  let onekey = String.fromCharCode(oneArray[0])
  console.log(onekey)
}

solution("FROG");
```

if my word is FROG. it should console log 70 since F is the first letter

Comment: `someword.charCodeAt(0)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`String.charCodeAt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt):

```js
function solution(someword) {
    let onekey = someword.charCodeAt(0)
    console.log(onekey) 
}

solution("FROG")
console.log(String.fromCharCode(70))
```

Comment: Why not just `let onekey = someword.charCodeAt(0)`?  What does `.split("")` accomplish given that `charCodeAt` already accesses a character in the string by its index?

Comment: @Wyck Good point. I've updated my answer. Thanks!